# what does "I am not feeling up for it" mean? when can you use this?

Tags: meaning

What does actually "I am not feeling up for it" mean?

Is it ok to use this phrase when somebody ask you to do lunch sometime and you actually do not want to go but want to be polite?

If you actually do not want to give the option of doing Lunch another time, what is the best way to say "no" politely without hurting this person's feelings?

Comment: Clarification: you don't like lunch, or you don't like the person?  Or, I guess, you only don't like how this person eats lunch?

Comment: The person was my former classmate who thinks I am a friend. But I don't feel that way and not interested in seeing in the future. But I want to say "no" in a polite way to kind of indicate that I am not interested. I am wondering if  " I am not feeling up for it" is a good answer or not.

Comment: "I am not feeling up" to lunch implies that you might be up for lunch in the future.

Comment: You do not want to use *not feeling up for it* in this case. Even worse, you might be inviting the person to ask you whether anything is wrong. As Val above indicated, the phrase implies that the condition is temporary. From an etiquette point of view, "No thanks" is both clear and polite. You cannot completely shelter people from having their feelings hurt, unfortunately. It is better to be clear.

Comment: It is very helpful to know the nuance of meaning of the phrase. Thank you.

Comment: We now have [Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), which might be a good place to ask your ‘‘what is the best way to say "no" politely without hurting this person’s feelings?’’ question.

Answer (score 2):

*I am not feeling up for it* is not idiomatic to me. It appears to be a conflation of two different expressions.

> I am not feeling up to it.

means "I am not well enough to do ...",

while

> I am up for it

means "I am willing to take part in ...", with an implication that the activity is in some way challenging.

Comment: I must have seen or read somewhere this expression, but I could not find it in the dictionary, so thank you for your clear explanation.

Comment: Why the downvote? Hot Licks says it is familiar to them - fine. But it is not idiomatic for me.

Comment: I had the same reaction you did. Perhaps it is a matter more of age than geography.

Comment: @ColinFine Well it is certainly idiomatic to me, an Englishman of what I suspect is similar vintage to your good self. And it is in the second adverbial meaning of *up* in the OED - sense 10e.

Comment: @Colin Fine  See later [What is the origin of the phrase "up for it"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314456/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-up-for-it)

Comment: @WS2: I'm completely happy with "up for it". It's just the collocation with "feel" that doesn't fit for me.

Comment: @ColinFine I think this has all got a bit confused. Someone, just today posted a question which has been referred back to this one. Only today's question was simply about *up for it* with no mention of *feel*. So I see what you are saying. But it still sounds idiomatic to me to *feel up for a game of tennis*, or *feel up to anything* - even if I do not *feel up to much*.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm not feeling up for it" is an expression used in the US to indicate that, while the speaker *might* be willing to engage in the proposed activity some time in the future, right now they're so tired/ill/busy/nauseated by the other party that they don't feel like participating at the current moment.

The expression has the "advantage" that some degree of fatigue/illness is implied to be the cause of this rejection (and it's not generally polite for the other party to "pry" as to the reason for the "feeling"), so it's not (overtly) a reflection on the other party or on the proposed activity.  As such, it's a reasonably polite way to refuse an invitation.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So this might be a good way to reply if you would like to indicate that you are willing to join another time. But maybe not for people you do not want to hang out with in the future, since it might give a hint that you are willing to go with them another time.

Comment: @pudding - Like all such things, if you politely reject an invitation several times most people will "get the hint", but some won't.

Comment: Maybe. Neither the British National Corpus nor the Corpus of Contemporary American English contains a single instance of _feel_ before _up for it_, though they both have a number of _[BE] up for it_ and _[FEEL] up to it_.

Comment: @ColinFine - It's not an expression that would be used in writing, only in spoken conversation.